# PHP: getting the URL from HTML by its URL descriptor

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

From within PHP, how can I get the URL of a certain href by only knowing its name/description text? For example, how do I get the URL to the site map from Apples main page by searching for the string 'Site map'?

So, when starting I only know the site I want to crawl (e.g. www.apple.com) and the URL descriptor I'm interested in (e.g. 'Site map'). The correct output for the solution should be: http://www.apple.com/sitemap/

Any idea on how to solve this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with an Regular expression?

```php
$url = 'http://www.apple.de';
$name = 'Site Map';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if(preg_match('/<\s*a[^>]*href\s*=\s*("([^"]+)"|\'([^\']+)\')[^>]*>.*?'.$name.'.*?<\s*\/\s*a\s*>/i',$content,$matches))
     print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Regular expression parsing of html, xml, etc is almost *never* a good idea.  [See our favorite stack-o answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). One of the many DOM libraries is a much preferred choice.

Comment: Thanks, the regex does the job and the result of your code snippet above looks like this:  
    `[0] => <a href="/legal/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a>
    [1] => "/legal/privacy/"  
    [2] => /legal/privacy/`

Comment: I updated the regex slightly. Works like a sharm: `preg_match( '/<\s*a\s*href\s*=\s*("([^"]+?)"|\'([^\']+?)\')[^>]*?>[^<]*?'.$name.'[^<]*?<\s*\/\s*a\s*>/i', $content, $matches );`

Answer (score 0):

After commenting in the negative on another answer, I don't like to propose my own, but this question looks maybe low-interest for many folks.

In HTML, urls frequently look like the following:

```
<a href="http://www.apple.com/sitemap/" >http://www.apple.com/sitemap/</a>
```

So, what you need is the `href` attribute of the url's tag.

There are *many* different ways to do this, and it's kind of academic, which is likely why few other people have posted answers.

To parse the page, a DOM Parsing library is the best choice. [Here is a good answer listing many options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/564406). Study some of them.

I, personally, like to use XPath-based DOM parsing libraries, and frequently use the DOMDocument library that comes pre-packaged with standard php.

[W3Schools has a pretty good XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that URLs in HTML many times looks like the example you show. However, in this case I know for sure that the URL descriptor is a static text (e.g. 'Site map') so based on this could you elaborate on how to solve this problem using an XPath-based DOM parser?

Comment: Html uses tags to identify conceptual portions of text. There is no concept of "static text" in html, it *will* be within a tag. I don't have time to answer in detail, but will provide some links. [Here is an introduction to Html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp). [Here is a stack-o question about how to parse a page using DOMDocument and DOMXPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493525/php-dom-xpath). Best wishes!

Comment: Allright, what I meant to say was that I know for certain that the web pages I try to crawl have the text string 'Site map' as a description of the URLs. Anyways, I guess I'll use the regex below since it works instead of trying to get a DOMXPath solution working.