# XPath does not work with XMLReader and SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, xmlreader

I get feeds from an xml feeder and his XML structure is like this:

```
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
<OddsList>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Bet-At-Home</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:32.943</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Over/Under 2.5</Type>
  <HomeOdds>2.22</HomeOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.58</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Interwetten</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:33.113</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Over/Under 2.5</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.85</HomeOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.75</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>188Bet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:33.27</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Over/Under 2.5</Type>
  <HomeOdds>2.11</HomeOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.8</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Pinnacle</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:32.803</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Over/Under 2.5</Type>
  <HomeOdds>2.33</HomeOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.65</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Bet365</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.263</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Handicap</Type>
  <HomeOdds>3.1</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.5</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>2</AwayOdds>
  <Handicap>-1</Handicap>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Bet-At-Home</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.373</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Handicap</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.17</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>5.41</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>10.32</AwayOdds>
  <Handicap>1</Handicap>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Mybet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.5</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Handicap</Type>
  <HomeOdds>3.35</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.5</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.85</AwayOdds>
  <Handicap>-1</Handicap>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Expekt</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:33.41</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Double Chance</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.15</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>1.85</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.3</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Bet-At-Home</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:33.787</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Double Chance</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.17</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>1.8</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.25</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Mybet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.037</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Double Chance</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.15</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>1.85</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.25</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>BetClic</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.16</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Double Chance</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.15</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>1.85</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.3</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Unibet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:33.52</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Double Chance</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.22</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>1.84</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.29</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>888</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:33.647</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Double Chance</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.22</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>1.84</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>1.29</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Pinnacle</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.733</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Asian Handicap</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.92</HomeOdds>
  <AwayOdds>2</AwayOdds>
  <Handicap>-0.5</Handicap>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>WilliamHill</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.623</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Asian Handicap</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.36</HomeOdds>
  <AwayOdds>3</AwayOdds>
  <Handicap>0</Handicap>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Betfred</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.86</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Asian Handicap</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.36</HomeOdds>
  <AwayOdds>3</AwayOdds>
  <Handicap>0</Handicap>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>188Bet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:34.967</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>Asian Handicap</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.89</HomeOdds>
  <AwayOdds>2.03</AwayOdds>
  <Handicap>-0.5</Handicap>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Doxxbet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:31.63</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.85</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.3</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>3.92</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>BetSafe</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:30.74</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.84</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.25</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.25</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Pinnacle</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:30.257</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.92</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.4</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.8</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>888</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:31.02</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.9</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.4</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Skybet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:32.177</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.91</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.4</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>WilliamHill</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:29.91</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.91</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.3</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.33</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Bet365</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:30.02</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.83</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.4</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.5</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Expekt</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:30.13</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.82</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.1</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.6</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Betfred</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:30.473</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.83</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.3</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.33</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Bet-At-Home</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:31.13</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.82</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.18</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.25</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Interwetten</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:31.397</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.8</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.4</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>BWin</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:31.77</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.85</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.3</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>3.9</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Mybet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:31.943</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.85</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.3</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>BetClic</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:32.067</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.82</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.1</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.6</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>188Bet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:32.27</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.86</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.15</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.05</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>10Bet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:32.473</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.83</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.2</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.4</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Sportingbet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:32.707</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.83</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.25</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.33</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>NordicBet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:30.63</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.84</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.25</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.25</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Ladbrokes</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:30.85</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.85</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.1</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.25</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>Unibet</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:30.38</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.9</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.4</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
<Odds>
  <FixtureMatch_Id>346076</FixtureMatch_Id>
  <Bookmaker>5Dimes</Bookmaker>
  <UpdatedDate>2015-06-20T19:42:31.507</UpdatedDate>
  <Type>1X2</Type>
  <HomeOdds>1.92</HomeOdds>
  <DrawOdds>3.4</DrawOdds>
  <AwayOdds>4.8</AwayOdds>
</Odds>
</OddsList>
```

and i try to get all where Bookmaker = Interwetten using this code:

```
$url = $this->buildUrl($name,$params);   
    $xml = '';

    $reader = new XMLReader();
    $reader->open($url);

    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $pathXML = array();
    while($reader->read() && $reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'XMLSOCCER.COM'){
        $xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom->importNode($reader->expand(),true));

        $pathXML = $xml->xpath('//Odds[contains(Bookmaker,"Interwetten")]');


        /*if($this->getExpression()){
            $xml->xpath($this->getExpression());
        }*/
    }
    //$pls = $xml->xpath('/OddsList/Odds/Bookmaker');

    var_dump($pathXML);
```

but var_dump retuns me

> array (size=0)   empty array (size=0)   empty array (size=0)   empty
>   array (size=0)   empty

I need to use XMLReader because that i need to get just conditions from xpath, not whole document...

Comment: You do not need `XMLReader ` to evaluate xpaths. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493525/php-dom-xpath

Comment: Yes i need, because i want to get just part of feed, not whole document.
SimpleXML is slow in search. This feed has 20 000 elements.

Comment: Show contents of $xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while, seems, not executed even once. Code should read, until needed condition will occur

```
 while($reader->read()) {
   if (reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'XMLSOCCER.COM') ) {
        $xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom->importNode($reader->expand(),true));
        $pathXML = $xml->xpath('//Odds[contains(Bookmaker,"Interwetten")]');
        /*if($this->getExpression()){
            $xml->xpath($this->getExpression());
        }*/
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yea, works now! Thanks!

Comment: One question please.
Does this code loads just searched feed into memory, or whole document and returns me search from his memory like SimpleXML, because this code takes time like whole document load...

Comment: Unfortunatly, i didn't work with xnlreader, but i think you need to use metod to expand only found node, or save fragment scaning the xml until  the close element of XMLSOCCER.COM

Comment: This answer did not provide an answer in the end (even accepted) as it resulted in just another question next: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30963733/367456 (just FYI)